# Is it possible to set my EditText to Invisible if the value is nothing or ""?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Good day, I am making a quiz application that required to type the answer. This is my 1st app.

My question have many sets of answer.

```
  final ArrayList<BasicItem> BasicList = new ArrayList<>();
    BasicList.add(new BasicItem("What is the Figurative meaning of [1]Water, [2]Field, [3]Fire", "Word", "Heart", "Word that consume", "", "", "", "", ""));
```

I put many string in advance because some question have answer up to 8 and each of answer have 1 EditText. So just like the code above, I only put "" if it isn't needed.

So it is possible to hide the EditText that isn't need or the one that have the value of "" ?
if so, how and where should I put it? Thanks for the help.

And, my toast isn't working

This is my code: (questions are draft only)

```
    final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsoundpress2);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsoundpress);






    answer1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.e("event.getAction()",event.getAction()+"");
            Log.e("event.keyCode()",keyCode+"");
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            switch (category) {
                case "Basic":
                    if (answer1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(BasicList.get(level).getbasicans1())) {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                case "Introductory":
                    if (answer1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(IntroList.get(level).getintroans1())) {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                case "Intermediate":
                    if (answer1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(IntermList.get(level).getintermans1())) {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                case "Advanced":
                    if (answer1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(AdvList.get(level).getadvancedans1())) {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                case "Sec1":
                    if (answer1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Sec1List.get(level).getsec1ans1())) {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                case "Sec2":
                    if (answer1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Sec2List.get(level).getsec2ans1())) {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    answer2.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.e("event.getAction()",event.getAction()+"");
            Log.e("event.keyCode()",keyCode+"");
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
                switch (category) {
                    case "Basic":
                        if (answer2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(BasicList.get(level).getbasicans2())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Introductory":
                        if (answer2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(IntroList.get(level).getintroans2())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Intermediate":
                        if (answer2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(IntermList.get(level).getintermans2())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Advanced":
                        if (answer2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(AdvList.get(level).getadvancedans2())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Sec1":
                        if (answer2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Sec1List.get(level).getsec1ans2())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Sec2":
                        if (answer2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Sec2List.get(level).getsec2ans2())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                        return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });

    answer3.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.e("event.getAction()",event.getAction()+"");
            Log.e("event.keyCode()",keyCode+"");
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
                switch (category) {
                    case "Basic":
                        if (answer3.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(BasicList.get(level).getbasicans3())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Introductory":
                        if (answer3.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(IntroList.get(level).getintroans3())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Intermediate":
                        if (answer3.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(IntermList.get(level).getintermans3())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Advanced":
                        if (answer3.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(AdvList.get(level).getadvancedans3())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Sec1":
                        if (answer3.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Sec1List.get(level).getsec1ans3())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Sec2":
                        if (answer3.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Sec2List.get(level).getsec2ans3())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                        return true;
                }
            return false;


        }
    });

    answer4.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.e("event.getAction()",event.getAction()+"");
            Log.e("event.keyCode()",keyCode+"");
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
                switch (category) {
                    case "Basic":
                        if (answer4.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(BasicList.get(level).getbasicans4())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Introductory":
                        if (answer4.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(IntroList.get(level).getintroans4())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Intermediate":
                        if (answer4.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(IntermList.get(level).getintermans4())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Advanced":
                        if (answer4.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(AdvList.get(level).getadvancedans4())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Sec1":
                        if (answer4.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Sec1List.get(level).getsec1ans4())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    case "Sec2":
                        if (answer4.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Sec2List.get(level).getsec2ans4())) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                        return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });


    switch (category) {
        case "Basic":
            textview.setText(BasicQuestion[level]);
            questionLabel.setText(BasicList.get(level).getbasicque());
            break;
        case "Introductory":
            textview.setText(IntroductoryQuestion[level]);
            questionLabel.setText(IntroList.get(level).getintroque());
            break;
        case "Intermediate":
            textview.setText(IntermQuestion[level]);
            questionLabel.setText(IntermList.get(level).getintermque());
            break;
        case "Advanced":
            textview.setText(AdvancedQuestion[level]);
            questionLabel.setText(AdvList.get(level).getadvancedque());
            break;
        case "Sec1":
            textview.setText(AdvancedQuestion[level]);
            questionLabel.setText(Sec1List.get(level).getsec1que());
            break;
        case "Sec2":
            textview.setText(AdvancedQuestion[level]);
            questionLabel.setText(Sec2List.get(level).getsec2que());
            break;
        default:
            textview.setText("error");
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I suggest using an array for the possible answers instead of having a fixed number of parameters. To check if a string is empty, check its length.

Comment: Your code is quit long, I suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, that is what i want to ask next haha. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't shown your Toast. Pleas add:

```
.show()
```

Example:

```
Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "back -> " + position  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And to hide any element, in the .xml file set default property is hidden:

```
    android:visibility="gone"
```

and whenever you want, it should show use if condition:

```
if ((value != "") && (value != null)){
   EditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @hafiza

Comment: Im gonna try it ^_^

Comment: what should i put in the word "value"? i already tried all my variables but it is still an error

Answer (score 0):

if it's a string in advance just check if the string is empty and write this:

```
mEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

you can also put a text watcher like that  and it will work whenever you change the the text of the textView/EditText

```
  mEditText.addTextChangedListener(object :TextWatcher{
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                mEditText.visibility=View.INVISIBLE// or gone
            }
        })
```